# python how to find the value of another field if matches

Tags: python

This is `json` file:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "url": "https://api.server.com/cables/100/",
      "termination_a": {
        "url": "https://api.server.com/interfaces/250/",
        "device": {
          "url": "https://api.server.com/devices/10/",
          "display": "device-number1-2023-08 myname (1718)",
          "name": "device-number1-2023-08 myname"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "url": "https://api.server.com/cables/200/",
      "termination_a": {
        "url": "https://api.server.com/interfaces/160/",
        "device": {
          "url": "https://api.server.com/devices/22/",
          "display": "device-number3-2023-08 myname (2245)",
          "name": "device-number3-2023-08 myname"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "url": "https://api.server.com/cables/300/",
      "termination_a": {
        "url": "https://api.server.com/interfaces/260/",
        "device": {
          "url": "https://api.server.com/devices/73/",
          "display": "device-number8-2023-08 myname (3678)",
          "name": "device-number8-2023-08 myname"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This is `txt` file:

```
this is device-number1-2023-08 myname1 and it is good.
this is device-number8-2023-08 myname8 and it is.
this is device-number3-2023-08 myname3 and it is not good.
```

This is my `python` code:

```
import json

with open('test.json', 'r') as j:
    data = json.load(j)

with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    for ff in f.readlines():
        ff = ff.split(' ')
        for jj in data['results']:
            jj_name = jj['termination_a']['device']['name']
            ff_name = f'{ff[2]} {ff[3]}'
            if jj_name == ff_name:
                print(f'jj_name --> {jj_name}, ff_name --> {ff_name}')
```

This is what I'm going to do:

```
if jj_name == ff_name, then print `url` of that name from json file and print ['termination_a']['url'] of that name from json file
```

This is expected output:

```
jj_name --> device-number1-2023-08 myname1, ii_name --> device-number1-2023-08 myname1, url https://api.server.com/cables/100/, ['termination_a']['url'] --> https://api.server.com/interfaces/250/
jj_name --> device-number3-2023-08 myname3, ii_name --> device-number3-2023-08 myname3, url https://api.server.com/cables/200/, ['termination_a']['url'] --> https://api.server.com/interfaces/160/
jj_name --> device-number8-2023-08 myname8, ii_name --> device-number8-2023-08 myname8, url https://api.server.com/cables/300/, ['termination_a']['url'] --> https://api.server.com/interfaces/260/
```

Comment: @CtrlZ thanks, I think using `re` as in the below answer is more simple for me myself than using `panda`. I think `panda`'s usage is for more complex scripts.

Answer (score 3):

You can use simple regex to read names in txt file and loop over results in json

```py
import json
import re

with open("test.json", "r") as json_file:
    json_data = json.load(json_file)

with open("test.txt", "r") as text_file:
    text_data = text_file.read()

txt_device_names = re.findall(r"(device-\w+-\d+-\d+ \w+)", text_data)
print("text file names: ", txt_device_names)

for r in json_data["results"]:
    if r["termination_a"]["device"]["name"] in txt_device_names:
        print("\nurls for device:\n\t", r["termination_a"]["device"]["name"])

        print("\t\turl: ", r["url"])
        print("\t\ttermination_a url: ", r["termination_a"]["url"])
        print("\t\ttermination_a device url: ", r["termination_a"]["device"]["url"])
```

### Example

since the sample files you provided do not have any matching names, here are another samples and the output of the code for them

**Text File**

```
this is device-number1-2023-08 myname1 and it is good.
this is device-number3-2023-08 myname3 and it is not good.
this is device-number8-2023-08 myname8 and it is.
```

**Json File**

```json
{
    "results": [
        {
            "url": "https://api.server.com/cables/100/",
            "termination_a": {
                "url": "https://api.server.com/interfaces/250/",
                "device": {
                    "url": "https://api.server.com/devices/10/",
                    "display": "device-number1-2023-08 myname (1718)",
                    "name": "device-number1-2023-08 myname"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "url": "https://api.server.com/cables/200/",
            "termination_a": {
                "url": "https://api.server.com/interfaces/160/",
                "device": {
                    "url": "https://api.server.com/devices/22/",
                    "display": "device-number3-2023-08 myname (2245)",
                    "name": "device-number1-2023-08 myname1"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "url": "https://api.server.com/cables/300/",
            "termination_a": {
                "url": "https://api.server.com/interfaces/260/",
                "device": {
                    "url": "https://api.server.com/devices/73/",
                    "display": "device-number8-2023-08 myname (3678)",
                    "name": "device-number8-2023-08 myname"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**Output**

```
text file names:  ['device-number1-2023-08 myname1', 'device-number3-2023-08 myname3', 'device-number8-2023-08 myname8']

urls for device:
         device-number1-2023-08 myname1
                url:  https://api.server.com/cables/200/
                termination_a url:  https://api.server.com/interfaces/160/
                termination_a device url:  https://api.server.com/devices/22/
```